# understanding load balancing in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, performance, load-balancing

I'm writing a website that is going to start using a load balancer and I'm trying to wrap my head around it.

1. Does IIS just do all the balancing for you?
2. Do you have a separate web layer that sits on the distributed server that does some work before sending to the sub server, like auth or other work?

It seems like a lot of the articles I keep reading don't really give me a straight answer, or I'm just not understanding them correctly, I'd like to get my head around how true load balancing works from a techincal side, and if anyone has any code to share that would also be nice.

I understand caching is gonna be a problem but that's a different topic, session as well.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

IIS do not have a load balancer by default but you can use at least two Microsoft technologies:

- [Application Request Routing](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/configuring-application-request-routing-%28arr%29/http-load-balancing-using-application-request-routing) that integrates with IIS, there you should ideally have a separate web layer to do routing work,
- [Network Load Balancing](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb742455.aspx) that is integrated with Microsoft Windows Server, there you can join existing servers into NLB cluster.

Both of those technologies do not require any code *per se*, it a matter of the infrastructure. But you must of course remember about load balanced environment during development. For example, to make a web sites truly balanced, they should be stateless. Otherwise you will have to provide so called *stickiness* between client and the server, so the same client will be connecting always to the same server.

To make service stateless, do not persist any state (Session, for example, in case of ASP.NET website) on the server but on external server shared between all servers in the farm. So it is common for example to use external [ASP.NET Session server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586.aspx) (StateServer  or SQLServer modes) for all sites in the cluster.

**EDIT:**

Just to clarify a few things, a few words about both mentioned technologies:

- **NLB** works on network level (as a networking driver in fact), so without any knowledge about applications used. You create so called clusters consisting of a few machines/servers and expose them as a single IP address. Then another machine can use this IP as any other IP, but connections will be routed to the one of the cluster's machines automatically. A cluster is configured on each server, there is no external, additional routing machine. Depending on the clusters settings, as we have already mentioned, a stickiness can be enabled or disabled (called here a **Single** or **None Affinity**). There is also a **Load weight** parameter, so you can set weighed load distribution, sending more connections to the fastest machine for example. But this parameter is static, it can't be dynamically based on network, CPU or any other usage. In fact NLB does not care if target application is even running, it just route network traffic to the selected machine. But it notices servers went offline, so there will be no routing there. The advantages of NLB is that it is quite lightweight and requires no additional machines.
- **ARR** is much more sophisticated, it is built as a module on top of IIS and is designed to make the routing decisions at application level. Network load balancing is only one of its features as it is a more complete, routing solution. It has "rule-based routing, client and host name affinity, load balancing of HTTP server requests, and distributed disk caching" as Microsoft states. You create there [Server Farms](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/configuring-application-request-routing-%28arr%29/define-and-configure-an-application-request-routing-server-farm) with many options like load balance algorithm, load distribution and client stickiness. You can define health tests and routing rules to forward request to other servers. Disadvantage of all of it is that there should be a dedicated machine where ARR is installed, so it takes more resources (and costs).
- **NLB** & **ARR** - as using a single ARR machine can be the single point of failure, [Microsoft states](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/configuring-application-request-routing-%28arr%29/achieving-high-availability-and-scalability-arr-and-nlb) that it is worth consideration to create a NLB cluster of ARR machines.

Comment: +1 on the edit (re: stateless, you can't "force" that on all applications, if it's needed for whatever reason, your last edit is perfect).

Comment: Statelessness is not an issue with ARR, which provides 'stickiness' out of the box: _"Application Request Routing provides a client affinity feature that maps a client to a content server behind Application Request Routing for the duration of a client session. When this feature is enabled, the load balancing algorithm is applied only for the very first request from the client. From that point on, all subsequent requests from the same client would be routed to the same content server for the duration of the client session"_.

Comment: so ARR is not true load balancing you will always be connected to the server you first connected to?

Comment: @CodeCaster, sure, you can also use _stickiness_ in NLB out of the box. The issue is that it is better to don't have to use it as the load balancing is then less flexible.

Comment: @dbarnes _"provides a client affinity feature"_. You can choose not to configure it. Konrad - of course it's better not to, but it's not always possible for existing applications as they can rely on server-specific resources.

Comment: @dbarnes, no. You can use stickiness in ARR and NLB, but you don't have to.

Comment: ok so if you choose not to configure it you have to go your own route using sql session or a different solution?

Comment: @CodeCaster, but as I said, Sesion is no problem, it can be shared among all farm if used externally.

Answer (score 10):

> Does IIS just do all the balancing for you?

Yes,if you configure [Application Request Routing](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/configuring-application-request-routing-(arr)/http-load-balancing-using-application-request-routing):

[image: ARR in IIS]

> Do you have a separate web layer that sits on the distributed server

Yes.

> that does some work before sending to the sub server, like auth or other work?

[No](http://blogs.technet.com/b/exchange/archive/2013/07/19/reverse-proxy-for-exchange-server-2013-using-iis-arr-part-1.aspx), ARR is pretty 'dumb':

> IIS ARR doesn't provide any pre-authentication. If pre-auth is a requirement then you can look at Web Application Proxy (WAP) which is available in Windows Server 2012 R2.

It just acts as a transparent proxy that accepts and forwards requests, while adding some caching when configured.

For authentication you can look at Windows Server 2012's [Web Application Proxy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn280944.aspx).

Comment: So what does the separate web layer take care of in this case? I'm assuming it's your custom written code, what logic do you need in that web layer?

Comment: The Application Request Routing is an HTTP layer in that regard that it sits between your clients and your servers. It assigns and routes requests to an application server. This layer is implemented by MS, not your code.

Comment: Ok so the load balancer's web layer is completely out of your control and you just "assume" you're still under single server instance?

Answer (score 5):

Some tips, and perhaps items to get yourself fully acquainted with:

- ARR as all the above answers above state is a "proxy" that handles the traffic from your users to your servers.
- You can handle *State* as Konrad points out, or you can have ARR do "sticky" sessions (ensure that a client always goes to "this server" - presumably the server that maintains state for *that specific client*). See the discussion/comments on that answer - it's great.
- I haven't worn an IT/server hat for so long and frankly haven't touched clustering hands on (always "handled for me automagically" by some provider), so I did ask this question from our host, "what/how is replication among our cluster/farm" done?" - The question covers things like

  - I'm only working/setting things on 1 server, does that get replicated across X VMs in our cluster/farm? How long?
  - What about dynamically generated,code and/or user generated files (file system)? If it's on VM1's file system, and I have 10 load balanced VMs, and the client can hit any one of them at any time, then...?
  - What about encryption? e.g. if you use DPAPI to encrypt web.config stuff (e.g.db conn strings/sections), what is the impact of that (because it's based on machine key, and well, the obvious thing is now you have machine(**s**) or VM(**s**). RSA re-write....?
- **SSL**: [ARR can handle this for you as well](http://blogs.iis.net/wonyoo/archive/2008/07/10/ssl-off-loading-in-application-request-routing.aspx), and that's great! But as with all power, comes a "con" - if you check/validate in your code, e.g. [HttpRequest.IsSecureConnection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.issecureconnection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), well, it'll always be `false`. Your servers/VMs don't have the cert, ARR does. The encrypted conn is between *client and ARR*. ARR to your servers/VMs isn't. As the link explains, if you prefer it the other way around (no offloading), you can...but that means all your servers/VMs should then have a cert (and how that pertains to "replication" above starts popping in your head).

Not meant to be comprehensive, just listing things out from memory...Hth

Comment: so that does seem like a problem about the IsSecureConnection, do you have to make sure all your servers have the cert then or is there a workaround?

Comment: @dbarnes I opted on the offloading - and not check, there is no reason to for me as the traffic between my servers _and the end user_ is encrypted. If you have certain PCI and/or HIPAA requirements, well, that might not be good enough/compliant. And if so, just like migrating certs from servers, you can do [export/import](http://www.digicert.com/ssl-support/pfx-import-export-iis-7.htm).